# Can in add icon/image to a button field without invalid the digital cert using pdfbox?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I want to add a image to a digital signed pdf without invalid the digital signature. What i found is using a button and insert the image as a icon into the button. But this is only workable in acrobat. what about PDFbox? can it do the same as well?

example:

[original pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V_FGNFeV8L6xXBAspSMnP90Tm8xnKIHc/view?usp=sharing)

[result i want](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pSHo_lWJk7XGjnagIrCXVSl3IPbBCuP6/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The PDF is certified, it allows "comments" but I don't know if this would include the widget annotation of a button.

Comment: If annotation changes are allowed, this includes changes of the appearance of a button.